# Como puedo solucionar al Hacer un Select me pueda mostrar en un input los datos seleccionados?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

Saludos a la comunidad

tengo un problema al momento de seleccionar un producto y me muestre el precio en el input si alguien de la comunidad me pueda ayudar estoy trabajando en una base de datos mysql donde esta la tabla producto

dejo el codigo muchas gracias

model:

@Entity
public class Producto implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idproducto", updatable = false, nullable = false,unique=true)
private Long idproducto;

@Column(name="nomproducto",nullable=false,length=40)
private String nomproducto;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date fecharegistro;

@Column(name="precio_venta",precision=10,scale=2,columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2)")
private Double precioventa;

@Column(name="precio_compra",precision=10,scale=2,columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2)")
private Double preciocompra;
```

jstl

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <select name="producto" id="producto"  required>
                                            <option value="-1">Seleccione Producto</option>
                                    <c:forEach items="${productos}" var="producto">
                                        <option value="${producto.idproducto}">${producto.nomproducto}</option>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" autofocus required/>
                            </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="pesobruto" id="pesobruto" onkeyup="restar();" autofocus required/>
                            </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tara" id="tara" onkeyup="restar();" autofocus required/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="pesoneto" id="pesoneto" disabled autofocus />
                            </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                <input type="text" pattern="\d*" class="form-control" name="preciocompra" id="preciocompra" value="${producto.preciocompra}"  required/>
                            </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="descuento" value="0" disabled  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body ">
                                        
                                        <button type="submit" onclick="agregarFila();" class="btn btn-success float-right " >Agregar</button>
                                       
                                    </div>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

javascript
function agregarFila(){

```
 let cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
 let preciocompra = parseFloat(document.getElementById("preciocompra").value);
 let pesoneto = document.getElementById('pesoneto').value;
 let descuento = document.getElementById('descuento').value;
 let producto = document.getElementById('producto').options[document.getElementById('producto').selectedIndex].text;    

 
 
 
 
 let subtotal=Number.parseFloat((preciocompra*pesoneto)-descuento).toFixed(2);
    
 
let impuesto=Number.parseFloat(subtotal*0.19).toFixed(2);
    impuesto= document.getElementById('impuesto').value;
let total=Number.parseFloat(subtotal).toFixed(2)+Number.parseFloat(impuesto).toFixed(2);
    total= document.getElementById('total').value;
```

//  let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

```
    let table = document.getElementById('tabla2');
  let newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
  

  let cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  let cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  let cel4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
  let cel5 = newRow.insertCell(4);
  let cel6 = newRow.insertCell(5);   
  let cel7= newRow.insertCell(6);
   
  
  cel1.innerHTML = producto;
  cel2.innerHTML = cantidad;
  cel3.innerHTML = preciocompra;
  cel4.innerHTML = pesoneto;
  cel5.innerHTML = descuento;
  cel6.innerHTML = subtotal;   
  
 

  
  cel7.innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Eliminar' onclick='deleteRow(this)'><input type='button' value='Actualizar'>";  
   

  
  calcularSubtotal();
  //deleteRow(tabla2);
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cambiando el select en el jsp:

```
<select name="producto" id="producto" required>
 <option value="-1">Seleccione Producto</option>
    <c:forEach items="${productos}" var="producto">
      <option  data-preciocompra="${producto.preciocompra}"  
      value="${producto.idproducto}">${producto.nomproducto}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

en el input

```
    <div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="text" pattern="\d*" class="form-control" name="preciocompra" id="preciocompra" value="${producto.preciocompra}" required/>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
<script>

  
    $('#producto').on('change', function() {
   
      let precioCompra = $('#producto option:selected').attr('data-preciocompra');
     
      $('#preciocompra').val(precioCompra);
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: Saludos algun moderador que pueda editar mi respuesta muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

mas allá del codigo que estas usando, aqui la prueba de concepto

```js
let myselect=$("#myselect")

myselect.change(()=>{
    $("#valorproducto").val("$"+myselect.val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Producto: 
<select id="myselect">
<option value="Selecione el producto">Selecione</option>
<option value="100">pollo</option>
<option value="200">pollo 2</option>
<option value="300">pollo 3</option>
<option value="400">pollo 4</option>

</select>

Valor:<input type="text" id="valorproducto" placeholder="Selecione el producto" >
```

no creo que se necesite mucha explicacion mas que el propio codigo